# ADB on lenovo N3

Tags: android, adb

I need to debug an app on some lenovo N3 ( N308 ) unfortunately it has no micro-usb port ( but the setting usb-debugging in developer options is there ) - Do I need a special calbe? Has anyone ever debugged something on this device? Anyone knows another way without rooting the device?

Comment: No offense, but I'm wondering how someone can post such an off-topic question while having such a high reputation. USB ports and cables don't have anything to do with programming, unless you're trying to implement some communication over USB ...

Comment: this is a development-related question - the highest chance to get an answer is IMHO here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way - it is possible to do adb over ssh here:
 http://redkrieg.com/2010/10/11/adb-over-ssh-fun-with-port-forwards/